# Is there a way to populate an sql dropdown field with active users in another project?

Tags: redcap

What I'm hoping to accomplish is something that would populated the SQL dropdown with all active users of another project.

The code below uses the a smart variable that only returns the current users. I was hoping to find a way that brings back a list of *all* active users.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [user-name] FROM redcap_data WHERE project_id = '450'
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with help from the REDCap consortium forum.

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM redcap_user_rights WHERE project_id='450'
```

Comment: To limit this to active users only, you could join this with the redcap_user_information table on username, and filter for "redcap_user_information. user_suspended_time IS NULL"

Comment: @Jangari, thanks! Is there a reference page that has a list of some of these more obscure options?

Comment: not really. Understanding the table structure, maybe using the DB Query Tool in Control Center, and then googling for SQL tricks, or ChatGPT, will be the best method to get exactly what you want in a SQL query. Also, join the community consortium. Lots of excellent help on SQL there.